# Understand how to clean store if we have exception between Splitter and Aggregator or recipient-list-router and Aggregator in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and we have created an SI flow where we have Splitter and Aggregator also recipient-list-router and Aggregator.
Today, while checking a code I got confused about how Aggregator will clean its store if we have an exception in between flow.
I am worried about the scenario where we got an exception between the flow and that creates stale state object in the system. 
I have checked the spring integration doc but no luck (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/aggregator.html).
I can see only one topic "Managing State in an Aggregator: MessageGroupStore" but that is for "application shots down".

Also, I did google for the same and I found one thread https://dzone.com/articles/spring-integration-robust but not able to folow much. Sure, I will come back if I am able to find some solution.

I am using OOB Splitter, recipient-list-router and Aggregator. Considering pattern should have mechanism handle this common scenario.

Can you please guide me

i.e:

```
<int:recipient-list-router input-channel="inputChannel" 
        default-output-channel="nullChannel">
        <int:recipient channel="aInputChannel" />
         <int:recipient channel="bInputChannel" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:service-activator ref="aHandler"
        input-channel="aInputChannel" output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel" />

<!-- we have exception in the bHandler -->
<int:service-activator ref="bHandler"
        input-channel="bInputChannel" output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel" />


<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel"
        output-channel="outputChannel" />
```

OR

```
<int-file:splitter id="splitile"
        charset="UTF-8" apply-sequence="true" iterator="false"
        input-channel="inputChannel"
        output-channel="bTransformerChannel" />
<!-- consider we have exception at 4th chunk -->
<int:service-activator ref="transform"
        input-channel="bTransformerChannel" output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel" />
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel"
            output-channel="outputChannel" />
```

Comment: I found one post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060523/spring-splitter-aggregator-handling-exceptions?rq=1). As per this, we need to use MessageGroupStoreReaper. "configure a MessageGroupStoreReaper as shown in the reference manual (or set a group-timeout in Spring Integration 4.0.x) to discard the partial group." Is this only solution to provide some time out and clear memory. I am thinking the framework should intelligent to handle the exception and empty group. Or all this parameter should be king of mandatory to avoid such scenarios. Please provide your valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; the aggregator is a "passive" component by default - all actions are taken when a message arrives.

To time out stale groups you can use a reaper or, with more recent versions, a `group-timeout`.